# jQuery ajax text file giving diamond shaped question marks

Tags: ajax, text

I am loading some content form a text file via ajax like so,

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url, 
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    success:  function(data) {
    data = data.replace('\\xa0','');
    jQuery("#div").html(data); 
    }
});
```

the text file loads but I am getting \xa0 diamond shaped question marks.  As you can see in my example I have tried using contentType and replace solutions but the questions marks still remain.

Am I using the wrong contentType?  How do I find the correct header for these text files?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

When using charsets, you should keep in mind that *all* of the files and sources should use the same charset. That is if your data source is in UTF-8, your JS and HTML files should also be saved in UTF-8. And of course the HTML doctype / meta charsets should match as well. Otherwise you'll be giving yourself a major headache, trying to convert between charsets programmatically.

P.S. The content type you have set in your example doesn't need to be set, as it is the default, according to jQuery documentation.